# Creating restfull service web with visual studio 2010

Tags: rest

I need to create a restfull service web using visual studio 2010. Can anyone tell me how to do?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would start by creating a new ASP.NET MVC Project and creating an MVC application that had only JSON returned by the controllers.

I did hear that the WCF team recently added some new stuff around REST that you might want to check out as well...but the MVC Project would still be my choice. You can check out the WCF HTTP Project at Codeplex to see if it interests you:

[WCF Community Site - WCF HTTP](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP)